# make subquery faster on large dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

i have a large dataset and i need help to make a few queries faster.

So far i am using subquery to retrieve the product ids and get the different persons of this products (something like filtering)

Here is my query

```
    SELECT assoc.*, count(assoc.product_id) as count FROM ws_products_persons_assoc as assoc 
        WHERE 
            assoc.product_id 
                IN 
                (   SELECT c.id 
                        FROM ws_products as c 
                    WHERE c.status = '1' 
                        AND ( ( product_name LIKE '%960%' ) OR ( ( code LIKE '%960%' OR isbn13 LIKE '%960%' OR parent_codes LIKE '%960%') ) OR ( publisher_name LIKE '%960%' ) OR ( author_name LIKE '%960%' ) ) 
                    ORDER BY c.year desc,c.product_name ASC 
                ) 

            GROUP BY assoc.person_id    
            ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0,30

Query Time =1.7937450408936 seconds
```

The subquery search in a few fields for the given keyword

The subquery returns 183473 rows and takes 1.7 secs to run.

Any ideas for making subquery faster is appriciated

Thanks

Comment: Avoid `select assoc.*` . Fetch only relevant columns needed
Do you really need `Like %..%` . it does not use any indexing (if exists). Try if you can work with `Like ..%`

Comment: `( product_name LIKE '%960%' ) OR ( ( code LIKE '%960%' OR isbn13 LIKE '%960%' OR parent_codes LIKE '%960%') ) OR ( publisher_name LIKE '%960%' ) OR ( author_name LIKE '%960%' )` Will surely cause performance issues on large data set as it ignores indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not an inner join? (assuming product_id is unique)

```
SELECT a.*, count(a.product_id) as count
FROM ws_products_persons_assoc a INNER JOIN ws_products p
          ON p.id = a.product_id 
WHERE
    p.status = 1 AND
    ( (p.product_name LIKE '%960%' ) OR
    (p.code LIKE '%960%') OR
    (p.isbn13 LIKE '%960%' OR
    (p.parent_codes LIKE '%960%') OR
    (p.publisher_name LIKE '%960%') OR
    (p.author_name LIKE '%960%' )
    ) 

GROUP BY a.person_id    
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by switching to `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.person_id, count(a.product_id) as count
FROM ws_products_persons_assoc a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ws_products p
              WHERE p.id = a.product_id AND
                    p.status = 1 AND
                    ( (p.product_name LIKE '%960%' ) OR
                      (p.code LIKE '%960%') OR
                      (p.isbn13 LIKE '%960%' OR
                      (p.parent_codes LIKE '%960%') OR
                      (p.publisher_name LIKE '%960%') OR
                      (p.author_name LIKE '%960%' )
                   ) 
            ) 
GROUP BY a.person_id    
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

For this version, you want an index on `ws_products(id, status)`.

The `select` columns should match the `group by` columns.

Comment: "Select fields different from Group by fields isn't a good practice." true @sagi but the later MySQL versions has something that is called **functional dependency**.. But it can only work if a.person_id is a primary or unique key which i doubt it is in this context.